# ReadXml showing Null exception error

Tags: c#, winforms

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

Am getting this error whenever am trying to read the xml file.

```
public static DataSet orads;    
String path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
path = path + "\\Mailconfig.xml";

orads.ReadXml(path);
```

I placed the xml file in bin folder of the application.
I couldnt find what mistake I made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you haven't initialized `orads`, you have just declared it, that is why you are getting the exception.

The following line only declare a `DataSet` it has not been assigned any value. Currently it is holding `null`

```
public static DataSet orads;
```

Later you are calling an instance method `ReadXml` on `null` object that is why you are getting the exception.

You need to instantiate it before using.

```
orads = new DataSet();
```

Or you may instantiate it with declaration.

```
public static DataSet orads = new DataSet();
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats the thing I missed.